# Prevent Maps from changing modes of direction

Tags: geolocation, maps, accelerometer

I was riding my bicycle downtown today listening to music and directions from my phone through my headphones.  Since I was riding my bike I wanted walking directions but any time I started picking up speed on the bike my phone would chirp "continuing with driving directions" and the next thing I know it's got me riding loops around streets that would be necessary if I were driving but were completely stupid and unnecessary for me on my bicycle.  Or once it even took me several blocks out of the way before I realized it was trying to put me on the freeway.  Very irritating.

Ultimately I realized that I wouldn't have this problem using the Google Maps app but ideally I'd like to be able to use the Apple Maps app without it trying to be smart and changing my directions mid path.  If I pick walking directions stay on walking directions. Can this be done?